# Openshift 3.9 How to ADD plugin to fluentD

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kibana, fluentd, efk

I have the EFK stack and want to add nginx log parses to fluentD in Openshift.
I read https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/parser_nginx
but I don't understand how to add a plugin in a daemon set. How is plugin added in fluentd to parse logs.

Comment: Can you paste current config for fluentd or configmap for fluentd daemonset in the question.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/NAKedFL5

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hm65VNsi and for daemon set

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for attaching configmap and deployment yaml. Can you try below config.

From [Parser Plugin Overview](https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/parser-plugin-overview). They provided a simple example to get nginx logs.

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /path/to/input/file
  <parse>
    @type nginx
    keep_time_key true
  </parse>
</source>
```

Can you add above config in configmap and try. The [nginx parser](https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/parser_nginx) is in-built, the link you provided is explanation of parser internals. If you don't like the way it is selecting/parsing, you can write your own.

Anyways, by using `@type` we can define type of parser we want.

PS: Right now I dont have any setup to test this. Also I have little knowledge in `fluentd`

**EDIT:**

I believe you already knew how `fluentd` is getting logs... In your pastebin link, at `volumeMounts` section, it mounting host's `/var/lib/docker/containers` which has all container meta data and logs, etc

Comment: I added that , how am I supposed to view teh nginx logs parsing in kibana now?

Comment: Again I have less knowledge on kibana and it's filter rules. You can search all logs from a kubernetes node and see nginx logs. Make sure you generate traffic on nginx pod. Verify connectivity b/w fluentd daemonset and ELK. I see `host` is commented in configmap that you posted.